# Using a variable to draw a line (canvas)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to use an input into a search bar (length (in the code)) to draw a line of 'length' length.

I've set up a very rough canvas area, the search/variable input but can't seem to link them together. Currently, I have the variable in the lineTo direction and it does plot, but only remains static even if the variable is updated.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var length = document.getElementById("myText").value;

}

var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.moveTo(100,25);
ctx.lineTo(length,25);
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="50"
style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
</canvas>
<input class="search" type="number" id="myText" value="Size...">
<button class="button" onclick="myFunction()">Size</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: The `ctx` commands you have up there run exactly once, then never again. If you want the line to change, you have to redraw it each time the length changes (and clear the canvas first): https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/h5u1qjmw/

Comment: Another way is to establish a draw loop that keeps redrawing the canvas (usually 60 times per second); in this case you only have to change the variable in the click handler: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/6n0b1ukp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The canvas interaction commands run once. To redraw each time, place the code inside the `myFunction`:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function myFunction() {
  var length = document.getElementById("myText").value;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(100, 25);
  ctx.lineTo(length, 25);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
}

myFunction();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="50" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
</canvas>
<input class="search" type="number" id="myText" value="Size...">
<button class="button" onclick="myFunction()">Size</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: I agree @ChrisG, but I don't see the issue - do you?

Comment: Yes, line commands need to be wrapped in `begin/closePath` calls (see my fiddles)

Comment: Fixed @ChrisG - any better?

Comment: Not to be rude, but I'm the guy who regards answers such as this as cheap points scoring, as gaming the site. If you feel you must do this, fine, but shouldn't you at least put in the effort to fix your answers yourself? Again, no offense. Better, yes, but does the line have the proper length? No. That's an issue in OP's code though.

Comment: Yes, sorry @ChrisG - I haven't worked with canvas before (apart from a tiny project) and I don't know many of the finer details.

Comment: Well, you're drawing a line from 100 to length. Which means a length of 100 creates a dot. See my fiddles for one way to fix this.

Comment: Thanks Jack and Chris, really helped understand whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="50"
style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
</canvas>
<input class="search" type="number" id="myText">
<button class="button" onclick="myFunction()">Size</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

I removed "value="Size..."" I don't know if you had more intentions with that

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

function myFunction() {
  var length = document.getElementById("myText").value || 100;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(length,25);
  ctx.lineTo(0,25);
  ctx.stroke();
}
myFunction()
```